# Insert data that stored in a table , into XMLspy? (for running diagnostics on the data ,later on) 

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd

I have a lot of tables of data , and I need to run diagnostics on the tables (their data) so , I want to insert the data into `XMLspy` , and generate xml file for the tables . Is it possible ? maybe with `Oxygen` ?

I've tried to look for a specific tutorial that can perform the following , however couldn't find any :

Take for example a simple table with few rows & columns , so I want to put its values

in a XMLspy , and then generate an XML file .

Is it possible to enter values with that program and eventually generate

an XML file ? If so , can you please direct me to the site / tutorial ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These days, many SQL engines have the ability to automatically generate query results formatted as XML. For example, Microsoft SQL Server provides a very simple mode, below is an excerpt from the [Online Books](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188273.aspx).

```
SELECT Cust.CustomerID, 
       OrderHeader.CustomerID,
       OrderHeader.SalesOrderID, 
       OrderHeader.Status,
       Cust.CustomerType
FROM Sales.Customer Cust, Sales.SalesOrderHeader OrderHeader
WHERE Cust.CustomerID = OrderHeader.CustomerID
ORDER BY Cust.CustomerID
FOR XML AUTO
```

A generated XML may look like:

```
<Cust CustomerID="1" CustomerType="S">
  <OrderHeader CustomerID="1" SalesOrderID="43860" Status="5" />
  <OrderHeader CustomerID="1" SalesOrderID="44501" Status="5" />
  <OrderHeader CustomerID="1" SalesOrderID="45283" Status="5" />
  <OrderHeader CustomerID="1" SalesOrderID="46042" Status="5" />
</Cust>
...
```

You could script this, to process the XML fragments as needed, or any other additional logic.

If you get to scripting, another simple approach that involves some scripting (C# on Windows) is to load an ADO.NET DataSet using some sort of query that represents the data that you want, and then serialize the ADO.NET to an XML file.

This script:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
class Script
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using(OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=NORTHWIND;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
        {
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select EmployeeID, LastName, FirstName, Title from Employees", cn))
            {
                DataSet d = new DataSet("Customers");
                adapter.Fill(d, "Customer");
                d.WriteXml(@"c:\temp\MyXml.xml", XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Will yield an XML with this structure:

[image: QTAssistant XML diagram]

If your database doesn't support this feature, or you prefer a different solution, and **if your XML must follow a prescribed XSD**, then I could speak for [QTAssistant](http://paschidev.com) (I am associated with it) that has this feature in place for quite some time; it is called XML Builder, and it basically uses an XML map between an XSD and a set of SQL stataments, structured to match the hierarchical nature of an XML document.

If you decide to try it out, you will have to register first to download the tool; the embedded help has a step by step guide on how to setup the demo, since it comes with a functioning sample, under the Modules > XML Builder > Samples > Recursive Sample topic. The sample requires a version of Microsoft SQL Server, but it could work with any other database for which there is an OLEDB provider installed on your machine, including Excel or Access.

When interactive, this is how the loaded sample looks like:

[image: QTAssistant XML Builder Module]